# How to parse dynamic element of email template with the value in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am getting a data from API which has a email body like this.

```
email_template{
body : '<p> Hello $_firstName, welcome to our application you have registered with mobile no. $_mobilenumber <p>'
}
```

I am hitting another API of user,to which i want to send this email, let's say "admin@gmail.com" which brings the data like firstname, lastname, mobileno.

```
user:
{
firstname : admin
lastname : admin_last
mobilenumber : 7894561235
}
```

Now how do i dynamically replace this value in email body ?

Answer (score 1):

You should just do a simple replace to do that:

```
updateEmail(template, user) {

const tempBody = template.body.replace('$_firstName', user.firstname)
                    .replace('$_mobilenumber', user.mobilenumber)
                    .replace('$_lastName', user.lastname )
  template.body = tempBody ;
  return template;
}
```